# ObjectInputStream from file causing memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a huge file with a list of objects written by ObjectOutputStream, one after another.

```
for (Object obj : currentList){
    oos.writeUnshared(obj);
}
```

Now I want to read this file using ObjectInputStream. However, I need to read multiple files at the same time, so I can't read the entire file into memory.
However, using ObjectInputStream causes a Heap Out Of Memory Error. From what I read, this is caused because ObjectInputStream has a memory leak and maintains references to the read objects even after returning them.

How can  I ask ObjectInputStream to not maintain a reference of whatever its reading?

Comment: I closed the stream while writing it. While reading it, I have around 100 files that I'm reading simultaneously and all those streams are open together. I only close them once the respective files have been read. However, the memory leak is definitely happening in ObjectInputStream since there should be only 100 objects stored in memory at a given time.

Comment: Why don't you try to read the files in batches. E.g for 100 files, you can make 4 batches, such that initially batch1 will be read which contain 25 file, then batch2 will be read.. and so on..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to call the method reset() on your ObjectOutputStream: “This will disregard the state of any objects already written to the stream. The state is reset to be the same as a new ObjectOutputStream. The current point in the stream is marked as reset so the corresponding ObjectInputStream will be reset at the same point.” (extracted from the java documentation)
Doing a reset on your ObjectOutputStream also resets the ObjectInputStream state.

I assume you can control also your ObjectOutputStreams?

Comment: Yes, I can control the ObjectOutputStreams, but I write to the files using ObjectOutputStreams before, using a different program and its not a socket connection. So will doing a reset on the ObjectOutputStream still affect the ObjectInputStream while reading?

Comment: @copperhead The object stream neither knows nor cares what it is writing to. I suggest you try it.

Comment: Waaau, it really works! I would never expect that the change must be made on the output side. I also noted that **too frequent reset()** is significantly **extending size** of the result file.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `writeUnshared` on the writing side you have already done one half of the job. If you now also use `readUnshared` on the input side rather than `readObject`, the `ObjectInputStream` will not maintain references to the objects.

You can use the following program to verify the behavior:

```
package lib.io;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ObjectInputStreamReferences {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final int numObjects=1000;
    Serializable s=new Button();
    ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try( ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os) ) {
      for(int i=0; i<numObjects; i++) oos.writeUnshared(s);
    }
    final ConcurrentHashMap<WeakReference<?>, Object> map
                                                  =new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    final ReferenceQueue<Object> q=new ReferenceQueue<>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        reportCollections(map, q);
      }
    }).start();
    try(ObjectInputStream ois=
        new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()))) {
      for(int i=0; i<numObjects; i++) {
        Object o=ois.readUnshared();
        map.put(new WeakReference<>(o,q), "");
        o=null;
        System.gc();Thread.yield();
      }
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  static void reportCollections(
      ConcurrentHashMap<WeakReference<?>, Object> map, ReferenceQueue<?> q) {
    for(;;) try {
      Reference<?> removed = q.remove();
      System.out.println("one object collected");
      map.remove(removed);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex){}
  }
}
```

Comment: System.gc() does practically nothing, and Thread.yield() even less.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the comment, but on my machine it makes the difference between getting one hundred reports of garbage collection or no report at all. I know that there is no guarantied behavior but at least with Oracle’s current JVM version 7 it works and that’s what it is all about, a piece of code for testing, not for production.

Comment: Which of those two methods are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP: I didn’t test them individually. I tested with that line and without. But I suppose that `Thread.yield()` is indeed obsolete on today’s systems but it doesn’t hurt anyway. As said, I wouldn’t use neither of them in production code.